# Unable to get performance improvements with __builtin_prefetch

Tags: c++, gcc, prefetch

I am trying to optimize an indirect memory access pattern using gcc's `__builtin_prefetch`

The access pattern looks like this

> A[B[C[i]]]      // i is induction variable

I followed the recommendation of the following  blog ([link](http://www-dyn.cl.cam.ac.uk/~tmj32/wordpress/software-prefetching-for-indirect-memory-accesses/)) to accelerate this access pattern. (The canonical example from the blog is shown below: )

```
for (i=0; i<NUM_KEYS; i++) {
  // The intuitive case, but also
  // required for optimal performance.
  SWPF(key_buff1[key_buff2[i + offset]]);

  // Required for optimal performance.
  SWPF(key_buff2[i + offset*2]);

  key_buff1[key_buff2[i]]++;
}
```

My code snippet is shown below

```
int prefetchOffset(64);
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (auto n=0; n < g.num_nodes(); n++) {
          /* prefetch instructions added */
          __builtin_prefetch(&degree_id_pairs[n + prefetchOffset], 0); 
          __builtin_prefetch(&new_ids[degree_id_pairs[n + (prefetchOffset / 2)].second], 1);

          /* kernel I wish to optimize */
          degrees[n] = degree_id_pairs[n].first;  //degree_id_pairs is a containers of std::pair<int, int>
          new_ids[degree_id_pairs[n].second] = n;
          inv_degrees[n] = g.in_degree(degree_id_pairs[n].second);
        }
```

Across multiple attempts (at tweaking the offset value), I was unable to improve performance. Worse, in most attempts, performance seemed to tank

Any thoughts why SW prefetches dont work for the indirect memory access pattern. I am confused because this is  a case that cannot be handled by the HW prefetcher

Also, tips on accelerating A[B[C[i]]] without prefetches are also welcome

System Information: Intel Xeon E5-2660v4 (14C:28T), Debian stretch (kernel 4.9), gcc-6.3 (Optimization level -O3)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE]. Your code is also missing many details, such as the compiler version being used, the compiler flags used, the architecture and the specific processor or microarchitecture the program is being run on. It's hard or sometimes even impossible to reproduce or debug performance problems without a detailed description of the setup combined with a MCVE.

Comment: Prefetch may require larger values of offset. What values have you tried? It may also just not be possible to speed up.

Comment: @JustinFinnerty I did a sweep from 2 to 128. Based on the recommendations of the blog post (linked above), I did most of my experiments with 64 (which I gather was a guess based on the DRAM access latency)

Comment: @YetAnotherPseudoName Since you havn't shown your code - how is anyone supposed to provide you with any help or look for mistakes you made ?

Comment: @tambre I didn't include any specific code because the snippets I am trying to optimize all have the access pattern of the example shown above. Also, since optimization using SW prefetches seems like black magic, I wanted best practises advice.

Comment: @YetAnotherPseudoName I have found similar results, I think manual prefetching is no longer of much benefit because the very deep pipelines and large multi-level caches on modern processors can do a good job.  And prefetching makes little sense with your openmp for loop, you do not know if the thread that performs the prefetch will be the thread that uses the prefetched value?  In this case prefetching is likely to cause massive false-sharing and significantly slow down the loop.

Comment: Prefetching this type of indirect pattern only helps to the extent that you can add to MLP beyond what the out-of-order CPU machinery already allows. On a "big" CPU like recent x86, there is a very large instruction window and other supporting resources which means that enough plain load instructions may already be issued in parallel to "max out" MLP, so prefetching doesn't help.

Comment: You do know that you're only trying to prefetch the last dereference (into A), all the prior ones would be issued as demand requests (C[i+offset] and B[...]). What are the sizes of each? how are elements scattered?

Comment: All the arrays involved are of int32_t. Regarding how the elements are scattered, I do not have that information before hand - the randomness of the access pattern would depend on the contents of B and C arrays.